# How to convert decimal (base 10) numbers to ternary (base 3)

Tags: r, radix, base-conversion

I was wondering if there is a way to convert decimal numbers to ternary, given that there is a function `intToBits` for converting to binary.

I actually need to convert a character string like

```r
> S0 <- c("Hello Stac")
```

to base 3. I thought to first convert it to decimal with

```r
> S01 <- utf8ToInt(S0)
> S01
## [1]  72 101 108 108 111  32  83 116  97  99
```

then convert the result to base 3. I want to obtain something like this:

```r
> S1
## [1] 2200 10202 11000 11010  11022 1012 10002 11022 10121 10200
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For practice, I guess you can try to write your own converter function like below

```
f <- function(x, base = 3) {
  q <- c()
  while (x) {
    q <- c(x %% base, q)
    x <- x %/% base
  }
  # as.numeric(paste0(q, collapse = ""))
  sum(q * 10^(rev(seq_along(q) - 1)))
}
```

or with ***recursion***

```
f <- function(x, base = 3) {
  ifelse(x < base, x, f(x %/% base) * 10 + x %% base)
}
```

then you can run

```
> sapply(utf8ToInt(S0),f)
 [1]  2200 10202 11000 11000 11010  1012 10002 11022 10121 10200
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice programming exercise. I have vectorized @ThomasIsCoding's answer to avoid expensive loops over strings and characters within strings. The idea is to loop over digits instead, since Unicode code points do not exceed 21 digits in any base, whereas the total number of characters in a character vector can be orders of magnitude greater.

The function below takes as arguments a character vector `x`, a base `b` (from 2 to 10), and a logical flag `double`. It returns a list `res` such that `res[[i]]` is an `nchar(x[i])`-length vector giving the base-`b` representation of `x[i]`. The list elements are double vectors or character vectors depending on `double`.

```r
utf8ToBase <- function(x, b = 10, double = TRUE) {
    ## Do some basic checks
    stopifnot(is.character(x), !anyNA(x), 
              is.numeric(b), length(b) == 1L, 
              b %% 1 == 0, b >= 2, b <= 10)
    
    ## Require UTF-8 encoding
    x <- enc2utf8(x)
    
    ## Operate on concatenation to avoid loop over strings
    xx <- paste(x, collapse = "")
    ixx <- utf8ToInt(xx)
    
    ## Handle trivial case early
    if (length(ixx) == 0L) {
        el <- if (double) base::double(0L) else character(0L)
        res <- rep.int(list(el), length(x))
        names(res) <- names(x)
        return(res)
    }
    
    ## Use common field width determined from greatest integer
    width <- as.integer(floor(1 + log(max(ixx, 1), base = b)))
    res <- rep.int(strrep("0", width), length(ixx))
    
    ## Loop over digits
    pos <- 1L
    pow <- b^(width - 1L)
    while (pos <= width) {
        quo <- ixx %/% pow
        substr(res, pos, pos) <- as.character(quo)
        ixx <- ixx - pow * quo
        pos <- pos + 1L
        pow <- pow %/% b
    }
    
    ## Discard leading zeros
    if (double) {
        res <- as.double(res)
        if (b == 2 && any(res > 0x1p+53)) {
            warning("binary result not guaranteed due to loss of precision")
        }
    } else {
        res <- sub("^0+", "", res)
    }
    
    ## Return list
    res <- split(res, rep.int(gl(length(x), 1L), nchar(x)))
    names(res) <- names(x)
    res
}
```

```r
x <- c(foo = "Hello Stack Overflow!", bar = "Hello world!")
utf8ToBase(x, 2)
```

```
$foo
 [1] 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111  100000
 [7] 1010011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011  100000
[13] 1001111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 1101100
[19] 1101111 1110111  100001

$bar
 [1] 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111  100000
 [7] 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100  100001
```

```r
utf8ToBase(x, 3)
```

```
$foo
 [1]  2200 10202 11000 11000 11010  1012 10002 11022 10121 10200
[11] 10222  1012  2221 11101 10202 11020 10210 11000 11010 11102
[21]  1020

$bar
 [1]  2200 10202 11000 11000 11010  1012 11102 11010 11020 11000
[11] 10201  1020
```

```r
utf8ToBase(x, 10)
```

```
$foo
 [1]  72 101 108 108 111  32  83 116  97  99 107  32  79 118 101
[16] 114 102 108 111 119  33

$bar
 [1]  72 101 108 108 111  32 119 111 114 108 100  33
```

Some caveats:

- For efficiency, the function concatenates the strings in `x` rather than looping over them. It throws an error if the concatenation would exceed `2^31-1` bytes, which is the maximum string size allowed by R.

  ```r
  x <- strrep(letters[1:2], 0x1p+30)
  log2(sum(nchar(x))) # 31
  utf8ToBase(x, 3)
  ```

  ```
  Error in paste(x, collapse = "") : result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes
  ```
- The largest Unicode code point is `0x10FFFF`. The binary representation of this number exceeds `2^53` when interpreted as decimal, so it cannot be stored in a double vector without loss of precision:

  ```r
  x <- sub("^0+", "", paste(rev(as.integer(intToBits(0x10FFFF))), collapse = ""))
  x
  ## [1] "100001111111111111111"
  sprintf("%.0f", as.double(x))
  ## [1] "100001111111111114752"
  ```

  As a defensive measure, the function warns if `2^53` is exceeded when `b = 2` and `double = TRUE`.

  ```r
  utf8ToBase("\U10FFFF", b = 2, double = TRUE)
  ```

  ```
  [[1]]
  [1] 1.000011e+20

  Warning message:
  In utf8ToBase("\U{10ffff}", b = 2, double = TRUE) :
    binary result not guaranteed due to loss of precision
  ```

  ```r
  utf8ToBase("\U10FFFF", b = 2, double = FALSE)
  ```

  ```
  [[1]]
  [1] "100001111111111111111"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cwhmisc::int2B`:

```r
library(cwhmisc)
int2B(utf8ToInt(S0), 3)[[1]] |> as.numeric()
# [1]  2200 10202 11000 11000 11010  1012 10002 11022 10121 10200
```

Answer (score 0):

This is near your question. I recently made a function that converts decimals (input as character representations of fractions) to their ternary expansion in preparation for the [Cantor-Lebesgue Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). You can adjust the function to prevent conversions of 2's to 1's and terminating expansion after the first occurrence of a 1. These features are specifically necessary for the Cantor-Lebesgue application.

The principal should be similar for your application. You can take the decimal form of your value and assume the second to the left-most value is your first remainder value and then enter the while loop. Your first value should be your first quotient, and equal 1. This process was based on a great post by [Mike Spivey](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70388).

```
bounds = c("1/3", "1/2", "2/3")

ints <- apply(do.call(rbind, strsplit(bounds, "/")), 2, as.numeric)

ternary_form <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(ints)){
  q = ints[i, 1] %/% ints[i, 2] # quotient for the ones place
  r = ints[i, 1] %% ints[i, 2]  # remainder
  
  build <- NULL
  count <- 1
  while(r > 0){
    q_new = (3*r) %/% ints[i, 2]
    r = (3*r) %% ints[i, 2]
    
    build[count] <- q_new
    
    # Cause values after N = 1 to become 0
    if(q_new == 1){
      break
    }
    
    # Break so the loop does not run too long
    count <- count + 1 
    if(count == 50){
      break
    }
  }
  
  # Change the 2's to 1's
  build[build == 2] <- 1
  
  ternary_form[i] <- paste(build, collapse = "")
}
```

Without editing, this should give you the vector ("1", "1", "1").